# Getting a UIKeyboard related animation just right

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, core-animation, uikeyboard

I am currently using `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` notifications to animate a user interface element in response to a `UIKeyboard` appearing on the screen.

I am calling a method

```
- (void) animateElement: (UIToolbar*) toolbar up: (BOOL) up
```

inside of the selectors that get called with the notifications are broadcasted. The method creates the animations and adds them to the appropriate layer.

Everything works well, but visually the experience is disappointing because the keyboard appears before the element is translated and therefore the transition feels abrupt, as the element momentarily disappears from view and then reappears at the right place. The animation is basically obscured by the keyboard animation.

Other apps like Path have a better transition, that starts sooner and is not obscured by the keyboard. Does anyone how it's accomplished? I can't think of a way to call it sooner, because the prior to receiving the notifications, the app has no way of knowing that the keyboard is appearing, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out the input accessory view

```
self.myTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.uiViewforKeyboardAttachment;//Can be any uiview
```

this will automatically attach to the kb for this text field.

That may alleviate your need to try to auto animate the toolbar.

Or you can use the animation duration within the notification.userInfo it has a key for UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey which will be an NSNumber. the doubleValue will be the duration of the animation.

that dictionary will also have UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey, UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey and UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey

All of those will help with the connection to the animation curve and start and end points.

I believe these are relative to the window or the first view within the window however. so be sure to convert to the view you need to know about.

Comment: you can put the same view on all your text boxes. and the keyboard will attach it all by itself. also you can use self.myTextField.inputView to replace the keyboard entirely.

Comment: This seems to gut the keyboard and just display the accessory view. That's so strange. I used `[myTextField setInputAccessoryView:accessoryToolbar];` and I can only see the toolbar (not the keyboard)

Comment: did you also set inputView on the textField ?

Comment: if you set inputView that will change the keyboard. you should only set that if you want to change the keyboard.

Comment: Right, I made sure to not set the `inputView`, only the `inputAccessoryView` which is why the result is mystifying.

Comment: Do I need to set some kind of default value for `inputView`? Because currently I am not setting anything for it at all, just calling `setInputAccessoryView`

Comment: no. it should be left alone. I guess that is pretty odd. but there has to be a reason.

Comment: I solved the issue another way, but this answer should still work, no idea why the keyboard just vanishes like that. May file a radar on this later.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is still wondering on the real values, my code looks like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^
 {
     CGRect sendFrame = sendMessageToolbar.frame;
     sendFrame.origin.y = self.tableView.frame.size.height - KEYBOARD_HEIGHT;
     sendMessageToolbar.frame = sendFrame;
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {

 }];
```

Take it with slow animations enabled in emulator and you will see it matches perfectly.

Comment: FYI: The kayboard notification contains the animation duration and curve in it's userInfo - if you use them instead of hardcoding values your code will work on all versions of iOS if/when Apple tweak their values. To access them use the constants `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html for the docs - theres a few more that are useful.